# Quickbook desktop : EmployeeModRq query is correct or not?

Tags: node.js, desktop-application, quickbooks

I have trying to change status of Employee Timesheet tracking for paycheck, But i receive the errors below,

> QB CONNECTION ERROR: QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream. (0x80040400)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
<EmployeeModRq><EmployeeMod>
<ListID>80001106-1476126466</ListID>
<EditSequence>1524123897</EditSequence>
<EmployeePayrollInfoMod>
<IsUsingTimeDataToCreatePaychecks>true</IsUsingTimeDataToCreatePaychecks>
</EmployeePayrollInfoMod>
</EmployeeMod>
</EmployeeModRq>
</QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Thanks 
Gopal R

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solutions, check the below one,

[image]

> **UseTimeDataToCreatePaychecks** and values is **UseTimeData**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
<EmployeeModRq requestID="6">
<EmployeeMod><ListID>80001452-1510608899</ListID>
<EditSequence>1522960465</EditSequence>
<EmployeePayrollInfoMod>
<UseTimeDataToCreatePaychecks>UseTimeData</UseTimeDataToCreatePaychecks>
</EmployeePayrollInfoMod>
</EmployeeMod>
</EmployeeModRq>
</QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Note : if you get any error like permission from administrator, Just do it like below,

> Edit ->
>
> Preferences ->
>
> Integrated Applications ->
>
> Company Preferences ->
>
> Choose corresponding applications and click the "Properties" ->
>
> In Access Right Tabs -> check last checkbox to enable as content like
>   (Allow this application to access the social security numbers/
>   Customer credit card information and other personal data).